# jquery fullcalendar overwrite buildSkeleton method

Tags: fullcalendar

I'd like to overwrite the buildSkeleton method used in the fullCalendar plugin.

I'm trying to remove the table,tr,td and replace them with regular divs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/basic/BasicView.js you'll see the buildSkeleton is a private function. However, renderBasic is public and makes use of buildSkeleton.

If you can successfully override the renderBasic you should be all good to go. However, your optimal path might be to actually fork the project (it obviously is open source) and add in the option of using a div skeleton over a table skeleton.

Comment: I ended up building my own implementation

Comment: @orbitory Another alternative is to use SlickGrid, which uses divs and at least markup wise seems better